# facet_wrap on ggplot not working for any data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to use facet_wrap on my data but it generates the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("absolute.units") : 
no applicable method for 'absolute.units' applied to an object of class "c('unit.arithmetic', 'unit')"
```

Its not an issue with my dataset or code since I have run this code successfully in the past. I ran the test code from the manual:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~class)
```

and it generated the same error. I updated the ggplot2 package but the error persists. Here is the output from session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.12.6 (unknown)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1.9000

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.5.0     lazyeval_0.2.0      plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.2.2     
 [7] gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.3.4     Rcpp_0.12.12     grid_3.2.2       rlang_0.1.2      munsell_0.4.3
```

I have tried googling the error without luck. Has anyone encountered this error or knows how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: cannot reproduce the error on 3.4.1. Try updating your R version.

Comment: Thanks that worked. And Now I feel stupid. PS: lost all my packages. Is there a way to retrieve them?

Comment: You could keep a list of your packages that you use and want have installed in R version as R script. The simply source the list. If you use R on windows there is a package caller [installR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/index.html), that does the package migration for you.